# How to detect if URL() constructor is supported by browsers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

I want to detect if a browser support the URL() constructor.

I want to use it like this:

```
const url = new URL(urlString, [baseURLstring])
```

I can't find a proper method to check if it's supported by browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the check needs to be done in JavaScript -

Use `if(typeof URL === "function")`

If true URL is supported

Sample Code

```js
if (typeof URL === "function") {
  const baseURLstring = "http://www.aaa.bbb/";
  let urlString = "/hello";
  const url = new URL(urlString, [baseURLstring]);
  console.log(url)
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1 && typeof URL === 'object') {
  const baseURLstring = "http://www.aaa.bbb/";
  let urlString = "/hello";
  const url = new URL(urlString, [baseURLstring]);
  console.log(url)
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks @SushantSalunkhe

Comment: @SushantSalunkhe Marked! Thanks again!

Comment: Instead typeof URL you should use typeof window.URL because your code would crash/

Answer (score 2):

1. If `const` is supported, URL is likely also supported - except
2. URL is not supported by IE at all it seems

   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL
   - http://caniuse.com/#feat=url
3. `if (window.URL) ...`